Syncing Github repository to AzureDevOps Repository
What Im trying to do is to sync repository in azuredevops to a repository in github. I did some googling and I stumbled into this article. It did not work right away but with minor modifications I was able to run the script from local Powershell successfully where the repository ADevops was populated from Github:
   $AZUREDEVOPS_PAT = '*****'
      $GITHUB_PAT = '****'
      Write-Host ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -'
      Write-Host ' reflect Azure Devops repo changes to GitHub repo '
      Write-Host ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -'
      $stageDir =  "C:\temp"#'$(Build.SourcesDirectory)' | Split-Path
      $githubDir = $stageDir +"\"+"gitHub"
      $destination = $githubDir +"\"+"Temp_Folder"
      #please provide your username
      $alias = 'some-owner:'+ "${GITHUB_PAT}"
      #Please make sure, you remove https from azure-repo-clone-url
      $sourceURL = 'https://' + $alias + '@github.com/some-owner/Source-Repo'
      $destURL = 'https://${AZUREDEVOPS_PAT}@dev.azure.com/Some_Org/Some_Porject/_git/Dest-Repo'
      if((Test-Path -path $githubDir))
      {
        Remove-Item -Path $githubDir -Recurse -force
      }
      if(!(Test-Path -path $githubDir))
      {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $githubDir
        Set-Location $githubDir
        Write-Output '*****Cloning Github remote secondary****'
        git clone  $sourceURL -q
      }
      else
      {
        Write-Host "The given folder path $githubDir already exists";
      }
      Set-Location $destination
      Write-Output '*****Git removing remote secondary****'
      #git remote rm -q secondary 
      Write-Output '*****Git remote add****'
      git remote  add --mirror=fetch secondary  $destURL 
      
      Write-Output '*****Git fetch origin****'
      git fetch $sourceURL -q
     
      Write-Output '*****Git push secondary****'
 
      git push  secondary --all -q
     
      Write-Output '**Azure Devops repo synced with Github repo**'
      Set-Location $stageDir
      if((Test-Path -path $githubDir))
      {
        Remove-Item -Path $githubDir -Recurse -force
      }

After that I created an azure devops pipeline and stored the github and azure PAT into variables so the script become like this:
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
  

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

# Starter pipeline
- task: PowerShell@2

  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    
    script: |
        Write-Host ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -'
        Write-Host ' reflect Azure Devops repo changes to GitHub repo '
        Write-Host ' - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -'
        $stageDir =  '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)' | Split-Path
        $githubDir = $stageDir +"/"+"github"
        Write-Host $githubDir
        $destination = $githubDir +"/"+"Source-Repo"
        #please provide your username
        $alias = 'some-owener:'+ "$(GITHUB_PAT)"
        #Please make sure, you remove https from azure-repo-clone-url
        $sourceURL = 'https://' + $alias + '@github.com/some-owner/Source-Repo'
        $destURL = 'https://$(AZUREDEVOPS_PAT)@dev.azure.com/Some_Org/Some_Project/_git/Dest-Repo'
        if((Test-Path -path $githubDir))
        {
         Remove-Item -Path $githubDir -Recurse -force
        }
        if(!(Test-Path -path $githubDir))
        {
          New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $githubDir
          Set-Location $githubDir
          Write-Output '*****Cloning Github remote secondary****'
          git clone  $sourceURL -q
        }
        else
        {
          Write-Host "The given folder path $githubDir already exists";
        }
        Set-Location $destination
        Write-Output '*****Git removing remote secondary****'
        #git remote rm -q secondary 
        Write-Output '*****Git remote add****'
        git remote  add --mirror=fetch secondary  $destURL 
      
        Write-Output '*****Git fetch origin****'
        git fetch $sourceURL -q
        #git pull secondary main
        Write-Output '*****Git push secondary****'
 
        git push  secondary --all -q
     
        Write-Output '**Azure Devops repo synced with Github repo**'
        Set-Location $stageDir
        if((Test-Path -path $githubDir))
        {
          Remove-Item -Path $githubDir -Recurse -force
        }

Here is screenshot of how AZUREDEVOPS_PATH is defined:

When I run this script I get the following error on the git push towards the end:
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled

When researching the error , a lot of post were suggesting  to check "Allow scripts to access the Oauth token but I cant find it anywhere!!! Nor the running Agent. Is that something set on the pipeline itself or in azuredevops settings. Why Im getting this error if it works locally in powershell. Is there an easier alternative to what Im trying to do vs writing powershell script and creating pipeline?
Thanks

Test the same PowerShell script in my pipeline and it can work as expected. Can you share screenshot about how you define the variable: AZUREDEVOPS_PAT. The option: Allow scripts to access the Oauth token  exists in the classic pipeline. In YAML Pipeline you don't need to enable it. And only when you use the system.accesstoken variable, the option is related. But from your description, you are using user PAT for authentication.

Hi, Thanks for the reply. I edited the post  to add screenshot for how the AZUREDEVOPS_PAT is defined. I dont believe its the varaible because when I hard code the PAT in the powershell script I get the same error!

can you try to change to use windows ms hosted agent and check if it can work?

On the other hand, can you confirm if you are using the same PAT as local powershell? The PAT needs to have  Code Read & Write permission enabled

So I chanved the vmImage value in the script to windows-latest and got the same error. I can confirm Im using the correct PAT as its hardcoded to url as I explained. I even copied the same hardcoded url to local powershell and it worked from there but not from the pipeline.

Are your Pipeline and synchronized repo in the same project? If no, you can try to disable the option: Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines  and Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines in Project Settings -> Settings (where the pipeline located)

The pipeline and the repository are under the same project , the pipeline however lives in different repository. It seems I dont have the permission to change those options anyway since they are greyed out

Can you try to use the following code to do the git push option? $B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`:$(AZUREDEVOPS_PAT)"))  and git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" push  secondary --all -q

I believe I tried what you suggested based on :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows
But I kept getting the prompt to Sign In when running this code from powershell!!!

Yes. The method is recorded in the doc. And if you input the PAT Token, it will not prompt out the sign in window in azure Pipeline.

On the other hand, do you mind if I share some simplified scripts to achieve the same functionality?

OK. I think something was wrong with my token. I deleted the old one and re create new one with Full Access permission and that seem to work. Im surprised that instead of throwing an error saying that I dont have the proper permission it just prompt me to log in

Do you mean that after creating the new PAT token, it can work now? When the pipeline shows the error:  could not read Password for...,  this means that the PAT token should have issue(not pass correctly or value have issue).  SO I keep asking you to check the part related to PAT variable.

Wrong password is different from invalid permission.  The PAT was correct but the permission was not and that's what is lacking.  When I searched the web for that error all were talking about the different way to pass the PAT correctly and changing oath settings . None mentioned permission.  I belive the changes thart Microsoft keeps doing  in a short amount of time wither UI related or security related makes something simple like this very difficult and confusing. Thanks for the help

Yes. I agree with your idea. The error message should be more clearly. This will be more helpful. Since the issue has been resolved now, you can add an answer to share the step.  This will be helpful to other users who have the same issue.

After struggling with this for sometime I was able to resolve with the following notes:
1- the issue turned out to be the PAT token itself not having the proper permission. Once I created new PAT and assign Full Access it worked! The remaining issue for me that I think Microsoft need to address is presenting more informative error message because none of the error messages I got indicated that its invalid permission wither in Azure devops pipeline or in powershell locally. All it was doing is trying to prompt me to re authenticate where in the pipeline its not able to do that because its disabled. In powershell if you cancel the authentication prompt this is the error message:
could not read Password for 'https://<PATP@dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJECT/_git/Repo': No such file or directory !!!
As you can see, there is no mentioning of permission issue.
2- In Regards to how to pass the PAT token , it seems there are couple of options out there and this since Microsoft has changed things few times in the last few years where its getting confusing.
I think before (and still working currently) you can do it as in:
https://<PATH>@dev.azure.com/Some_Org/Some_Porject/_git/Repo

However I always recommend you verify with Microsoft documentation because again things might change and by the time you read this who knows what formatting or authentication mechanism Microsoft promote. The current documentation recommends that you do it like this:
$MyPat = 'yourPat'
$headerValue = "Authorization: Basic " + [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":" + $MyPat))
$env:GIT_AUTH_HEADER = $headerValue

git --config-env=http.extraheader=GIT_AUTH_HEADER clone https://dev.azure.com/yourOrgName/yourProjectName/_git/yourRepoNam

Now to add to the confusion, if you keep reading the referenced documentation under "Existing repos" you will find yet another format:
git remote add origin https://dev.azure.com/<PAT>@<company_machineName>:/<path-to-git-repo> path to git repo = <project name>/_git/<repo_name> git push -u origin --all

not sure what the  <company_machineName> suppose to be, and what does it have to do with Git authentication. This format did not work to no matter how I try  I keep getting error 400 invalid url.
3- However , if you are trying to do it from Azure Pipeline some post recommends to use System.AccessToken :
 $env:GIT_AUTH_HEADER = "Authorization: Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"

but this one you need to make sure you set the right permission other wise you will get 403 Forbidden error see this post, Or copy whatever Id is given to you in the error message go to the repository security settings  and in the search box paste the Id, whatever this Id is associated with youn need to set Allow for Contribute Permission and whatever permission you need. Goodluck finding any clear documentation from Microsoft about this.
4- There is 4th way you can authenticate but I dont recommend it because it has username & password in it and its not clear how long those credentials remain valid before they expire. Basically go the repository under Devops and click the Clone Button you will see Generate Git Credentials :

Click on the "" and you will be given username and password which you can use in the repo url in the format of :
https://<username>:<password>@dev.azure.com/ORG/PROJECT/_git/REPO

Im not sure what are the use cases for this but it works.Again Could not find any clear microsoft doc on this.
As you can see there are many of options , some are probably legacy and some are new. I think the pace in which things are changing from one version to another and lack of documentation makes things more confusing.
5- Finally, Why Im doing all this? It goes back to the simple scenario where I wanted to create a pipeline to sync Github repository to Azure Devops Repository.Unfortunately it doesnt seem that there is direct out of the box way to do it and you probably have to write the pipeline with all of the right Git commands. However how to trigger this pipeline so that it sync everytime you are making changes in github to certain branch there is very informative youtube about this that helped me a lot:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZlaoNPzaxA&t=206s
Thanks to Kevin Lu-MSFT for trying to help me with this.
